# How to create a Json in REST Web Service for Grails?

Tags: grails

i create two domain, Author and Book, the Author has many Book, and the Book is belongsTo Author.

```
class Author {
     hasMany = [ books : Book ]
     String name
}

class Book {
    String title
    Author author
}
```

this "savebook" function in BookController.groovy

```
   def savebook={

        def json = request.JSON
        def bookInstance = new Book()
        bookInstance.properties = json

        bookInstance.author_id = json.author_id
        bookInstance.title = json.title         

        if (bookInstance.validate()) {
            bookInstance.save();
            def rep = [ respence: "1" ] // save
            render rep as JSON
        }

        else {
            def rep = [ respence: "0" ] // not save
            render rep as JSON
        }

    }
```

I have not found a solution for the line : `bookInstance.author_id = json.author_id` in "savebook" to create a book by an author. 
My second question is how should be the structure of the JSON object to make a REST POST ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question you need to look the author up by their id and assign that instance to the author variable in Book:

```
def author = Author.get(json.author_id)
bookInstance.author = author
bookInstance.title = json.title
author.addToBooks(bookInstance)
```

The structure of the JSON coming into the rest method can be any valid JSON.  You could simply do

```
{
    "author_id": 12345,
    "title" : "See Jane Run"
}
```

or you could get as complicated as you need.